# How to get a File reference from within a JAR

Tags: java, jar

First of all I would like to add that I probably have tried every proposed solution on SO about this issue but still cant get it working.

So this is my problem...

I have an application for parsing XML files. I select an xml file (source) and I validate it against an xsd (this is the file inside my JAR that I cant access). Running the code from within my IDE works fine:

```
xsd = new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("xsds/2014/schema.xsd").getFile());
System.out.println(xsd.getAbsolutePath());
//returns: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaXMLValidator\build\classes\app\xsds\2014\schema.xsd
```

But when I build by application to JAR file and I run it I cant get the reference to that file. 
When I run the application from within my JAR i get this:

```
//returns: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaXMLValidator\dist\file:C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaXMLValidator\dist\JavaXMLValidator.jar!\app\xsds\2014\schema.xsd
```

The path looks ok (i think) but I cant get a correct reference to my file in the code:

```
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(xsd);
Schema schema = null;
try {
    schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
} catch (SAXException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid XML Schema Selected!!!\n Exception: "+this.getStackTraceString(ex,"    "));
    return;
}
```

I get the exception:

```
SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 
'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaXMLValidator\dist\file:C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaXMLValidator\dist\JavaXMLValidator.jar!\app\xsds\2014\schema.xsd',
because 1)could not find the document;
2)the document could not be read;
3)the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>
........
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I could have a correct reference to the xsd file withing the JAR?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: The short answer is, you can't and you shouldn't.  Use the `URL` or `InputStream` to extract the resource to disk if you "really" need a `File` reference.  Remember, once added to a Jar file, the "file" is embedded within a zip container and can no longer be referenced as a `File` would be if it resided on disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example there is a project with such structure:

```
testproject
  xsdfolder
    schema.xsd
  javaclassfolder
    SomeClass.java

public static class SomeClass {

    public static URL getLocalXsd() throws MalformedURLException {
      URL baseUrl = SomeClass.class.getResource(SomeClass.class.getSimpleName() + ".class");
      return new URL(baseUrl, "../xsdfolder/schema.xsd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As MadProgrammer says, use the `URL`:

```
URL xsd = getClass().getResource("xsds/2014/schema.xsd");
Schema schema = null;
try {
    schema = factory.newSchema(xsd);
} catch (SAXException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid XML Schema Selected!!!\n Exception: "+this.getStackTraceString(ex,"    "));
    return;
}
```